# How to create delete button for each list and add number system for order list

Tags: javascript

How to create delete button for each list and add number system for order list. i am looking for pure java script answer

```css
function btnClicked(){
 var sample = prompt("Please enter item number","");
 var list = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");

 list[0].innerHTML =list[0].innerHTML + "<li class='list-group-item '>" + sample + "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm text-right float-right'>Delete It!</button> </li>";


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row" style="padding: 20px 0px;">
  <div class="col-md-6 bg-dark"  style="padding: 20px 20px;">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="btnClicked()">Add Items</button>



   <ul class="listItem list-group pt-2 ">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cakes <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm text-right float-right">Delete It!</button> </li>
    
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`elem.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

**updated**:
delete newly created item also

```js
function btnClicked() {
  var sample = prompt("Please enter item number", "");
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");
  list[0].innerHTML = list[0].innerHTML + "<li class='delete list-group-item '>" + sample + "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm text-right float-right'>Delete It!</button> </li>";
  initilize();
}
initilize()

function initilize() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.delete').forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
      elem.closest('.list-group-item').remove()
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="padding: 20px 0px;">
    <div class="col-md-6 bg-dark" style="padding: 20px 20px;">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="btnClicked()">Add Items</button>



      <ul class="listItem list-group pt-2 ">
        <li class="list-group-item">Cakes <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm text-right delete float-right">Delete It!</button> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm it works. btw how to use number system for list

Comment: what you mean by number system?

Comment: how to apply this button new add item

Comment: still not understand ? `this button` ?

Comment: how to delete new created list item

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to attach event listener for every time you have added the new item. What you need is to use event [delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row" style="padding: 20px 0px;">
  <div class="col-md-6 bg-dark"  style="padding: 20px 20px;">
   <button class="btn btn-primary add-btn">Add Items</button>



   <ul class="listItem list-group pt-2 ">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cakes <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm text-right float-right delete-btn">Delete It!</button> </li>
    
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
     const addItem = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const value = prompt('Please enter the item name');
            
            if (value) {
             const itemString = `
                 <li class="list-group-item">${value} <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm text-right float-right delete-btn">Delete It!</button> </li>
                `;
                
    const itemContainer = document.querySelector('.listItem');
                
                itemContainer.innerHTML += itemString;
            }
          }
          
          const deleteItem = function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

                // Check if the click target is the delete button then remove the parent element.
                if (evt.target && evt.target.matches('button.delete-btn')) {
                 evt.target.parentElement.remove();
                }
          }
          
          const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
          addBtn.addEventListener('click', addItem);
          
          // Attach event listener to the document and perform event delegation.
          document.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
    });
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```